# Чем заменить UPDATE чтобы уменьшить время выполнения запроса?

Tags: mysql, sql

Я вставляю (или обновляю уже существующие такие же записи) подряд около 10k строк. `INSERT` работает очень быстро, буквально мгновенно, а вот `UPDATE` работает крайне медленно. Если сначала удалять строку, а потом снова вставлять (а это расходует ID что не очень хорошо) то производительности не прибавится. Есть ли возможность обновлять строки так же быстро, как и вставлять, и если есть, то как реализовать это?

**UPD:** вот как я обновляю

```
UPDATE `posts` SET `reposts` = '$preposts', likes = '$plikes', text = '$ptext', `att1_type` = '$att1t', `att1_data` = '$att1c', `att2_type` = '$att2t', `att2_data` = '$att2c', `att3_type` = '$att3t', `att3_data` = '$att3c', `att4_type` = '$att4t', `att4_data` = '$att4c', `att5_type` = '$att5t', `att5_data` = '$att5c', `att6_type` = '$att6t', `att6_data` = '$att6c', `att7_type` = '$att7t', `att7_data` = '$att7c', `att8_type` = '$att8t', `att8_data` = '$att8c', `att9_type` = '$att9t', `att9_data` = '$att9c', `att10_type` = '$att10t', `att10_data` = '$att10c'  WHERE `groupid` = '$groupid' AND postid = '$postid'
```

**UPD2:** по просьбе @cheops выполнил запрос `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM posts WHERE groupid = '$groupid' AND postid = '$postid', заменив их на конкретные поля из БД:
[image: запрос]

Структура таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `groupid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `postid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reposts` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` text,
  `att1_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att1_data` text,
  `att2_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att2_data` text,
  `att3_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att3_data` text,
  `att4_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att4_data` text,
  `att5_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att5_data` text,
  `att6_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att6_data` text,
  `att7_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att7_data` text,
  `att8_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att8_data` text,
  `att9_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att9_data` text,
  `att10_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `att10_data` text,
  `hash` text NOT NULL,
  `usid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `orid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `favorites` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `whenscore` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: А какое условие стоит в запросах update и delete ? Может у вас там идет поиск записи по столбцу, по которому нет индекса, например, то будет тормозить не обновление/удаление, а предварительный поиск в таблице строки, которая меняется

Comment: @Mike я добавил в вопрос код обновления

Comment: Выполните пожалуйста запрос EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `groupid` = '$groupid' AND postid = '$postid'. Если не сложно прикрепите результаты к вопросу. Как вариант - очень долгий поиск по условию.

Comment: @cheops выполнил в phpmyadmin и добавил к вопросу.

Comment: @DeFF Ну так он как я и подозревал полным перебором идет. видите в keys и даже в possible_keys ничего не стоит вам нужен индекс как минимум по одному из полей участвующих в выборке или совмещенный индекс по обоим полям. посмотрите все запросы существующие в системе что бы понять по каким полям наиболее часто идет выборка/обновление что бы построить правильные индексы и не сделать при этом лишних

Comment: @DeFF Хотя очень странно, почему у вас нет индекса по postid, я так подозреваю это же основной id в вашей таблице. приведите код создания вашей таблици

Comment: @Mike у меня основной ID в таблице - поле `ID`, но искать на данный момент удобнее по postid и groupid. Если поиск по `ID` ускорит работу, то я могу немного поменять свой скрипт и искать по `ID`.

Comment: @Mike добавил код создания

Comment: @DeFF Вопрос в том, где и как вы этот ID будете получать. Если вам для его получения не понадобится еще по нескольким таблицам выбирать какие нибудь записи дополнительно к текущему - то так и сделайте. Выборка по ID в любом случае ускорит операцию.

Comment: *оффтопик: А когда у какой-то записи потребуется 11 атрибутов, вы будете вставлять еще одно поле?

Comment: @DeFF Кстати, предыдущийц скриншот лучше показывл текущую ситуацию у вас в коде создания нет key вообще и не указан автоинкремент. но в принципе и так уже все ясно

Comment: @Mike т.е. вы использовать `ID` всё же разумнее чем использовать индексы?

Comment: @DeFF В принципе да. Лишние индексы - лишняя нагрузка. Любой запрос, выполняющийся на таблице с несколькими тыс. строк без индекса - это катастрофа. Так что тут из двух зол надо выбрать меньшее. Если у вас в системе куча запросов идет по postid, например то может и стоит сделать индекс где он будет первым и не парится.

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое за помощь. Я пока поэкспериментирую и с индексами, и с выборкой по ID и дальше уже решу, что делать.

Comment: @DeFF Кстати, от создания одного индекса у вас вставка _заметно_ не замедлится. вот когда вы будете 1 млн. записей вставлять - то тогда почувствуете разницу. обратите внимание на порядок полей в индексе. Если данный update идет по полям groupid И postid то ему все равно в какой последоветельности поля. Но если у вас в системе есть например десяток запросов в которых в where _только_ postid (а не первом месте у вас goupid) то он не сможет воспользоваться данным индексом. если же поля в индексе переставить - то сможет. поэтому и говорю, надо смотреть не 1 конкретный запрос, а в комплексе все

Comment: @Mike спасибо за дополнительную информацию. У меня используется именно такой порядок, как был задан в индексе (из-за привычки я делал так везде и буду делать так дальше), так что индексы будут работать точно. Другое дело когда будет миллион записей (а так, возможно, будет). Я поразмыслю над всем написанным в данном вопросе, поэкспериментирую и, думаю, приду к окончательному решению.

Comment: @DeFF Порядок условий в where не важен. важно наличие поля. индекс построенный на `(groupid, postid)` помогает в работе запросов `where groupid=X and postid=Y`и `where postid=X and groupid=Y` и даже `where groupid=X`, но не поможет для `where postid=Y`(без groupid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, попробуйте все-таки проиндексировать таблицу

```
CREATE INDEX groupid_postid_idx ON posts (groupid, postid);
```

Вообще индексы замедляют вставку и изображения, так как требуется время на их перестроение. Однако, у вас здесь поиск идет с полным сканом таблицы, возможно дело в этом и индекс поможет ускорить операцию.

Comment: Я так и не понял из вашего ответа, индексы ускорят или замедлят?

Comment: Перед тем как предлагать конкретный индекс надо понять структуру таблицы и какие выборки наиболее частые. плюс к этому стоит выносить первым в индекс поле по которому могут идти отдельные операции, без упоминания второго поля и у которого большая селективность

Comment: @DeFF Индексы ускоряют выборку (и выборку для update/delete в том числе), но замедляют вставку новых записей. Поэтому лучше грамотно подойти к тому по какому полю/полям конкретно построить индекс

Comment: Я предлагаю просто проверить - будет быстрее или медленнее. Если мы создадим индекс и проверим локально, ускоряется операция или нет - ничего же не произойдет кардинального, индекс, конечно, потом нужно удалить. Так как пока не понятно вообще что происходит.

Comment: Этот запрос индекс точно ускорит, DeFF, просто нужно будет посмотреть изменилось ли время обновления.

Comment: @cheops да, действительно, создание индекса ускорило обновление и теперь это происходит очень быстро, да и вставка полей медленнее не стала.

Comment: Будьте аккуратны с индексами - если их будет много, пойдет обратный процесс, операции INSERT, DELETE и UPDATE будут замедляться.

Comment: @cheops у меня будет очень много полей в таблице. И что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Нет, имеется в виду количество индексов. Есть соблазн натыкать их много, мне в продакшене встречаются базы где их по 20 на таблицу - это явный перебор. У вас индекс один (точнее два, если учитывать первичный ключ) - пока все не так плохо, просто оставьте его. Но если вы будете их добавлять и добавлять - это закончится плохо. Лучше всего погонять запросы EXPLAIN и посмотреть где еще индексов не хватает и вообще продумать индексацию базы.

Comment: Просто у MySQL есть особенность, в одном запросе/подзапросе используется какой-то один индекс (даже если подходит несколько). Т.е. вы можете им ускорить какой-то конкретный запрос, а вот перестраиваются они при каждой вставке/обновлении/удалении.

Comment: @cheops спасибо большое за помощь. Буду разбираться подробнее с индексами.